# Read filenames from CSV and then copy the files to different directory -part 2

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to write a python code that will read csv and after reading look for the files in the directory and then move the files to the destination folder. I'm using Python 3.6.

I have the same problem which is defined in the code here: [Read filenames from CSV and then copy the files to different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850220/read-filenames-from-csv-and-then-copy-the-files-to-different-directory)

I tried there method but when i run this code it says not **such file or directory**

below is code which i modified, in the code they used agrv but i am defining the path...

```
import os
import shutil
import csv
import sys

csv_file = "maharera.csv"
existing_path_prefix = "D:\maharera"
new_path_prefix = "D:\movement"

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        filename = row[0]
        filepath = row[1]

        new_filename = os.path.join(new_path_prefix, filename)
        shutil.copy(filepath, new_filename)
```

i am trying to move files from d drive to drive but in different folder but files should be same from csv file..

**CSV is attached here** https://www.dropbox.com/s/0t9skcuje6jyew1/maharera.csv?dl=0

in csv there are two columns one is filename and other is there current destination where are they are kept right now...

there new destination is mentioned into code

Comment: How about `shutil.copy(os.path.join(filepath, filename), new_filename)`?

Comment: I received the same error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filepath\\filename'

Comment: `'filepath\\filename'` comes from the header/first row of your csv file, you should skip it.

Comment: oh yes..it is working......thank you so much for your help..really thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes are found in your code.

1. you include the header/first row of your csv file.
2. you are trying to copy the folder of the file instead of the file itself.

To avoid the errors, you can try

```
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0:
            pass    # Skip header row
        else:
            filename, filepath = row
            new_filename = os.path.join(new_path_prefix, filename)
            old_filename = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
            shutil.copy(old_filename, new_filename)
```

Comment: Thank you so much...both the codes are working fine..and this one is really good...